# Notation for operation which takes the difference of two numbers if it is positive, zero otherwise

Tags: notation

Is there a mathematical notation for a function like Fortran's [dim()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DIM.html)?

Comment: $\max(0, [a-b]).$

Comment: @user2661923 Short and elegant (+1)

Comment: why are the square brackets needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation is called [truncated subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monus#Natural_numbers)  (or sometimes *monus*) , and is often symbolized with $$∸$$ a minus sign with a dot over it.  For example:

$$a∸b=\begin{cases}
a-b,& \text{if $a≥b$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

or

$$(a∸b) + (b∸a) = |a-b|.$$